# How to identify abstract and concrete sentences using python NLP tools?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, spacy

How to identify if a sentence quantifies something in concrete or abstract terms using tools like spacy, nltk, or any other NLP tools available in python.

How do I approach this problem? Are there any pre-trained classifiers that can serve this requirement? Is there a way to use the POS tags and other methods to achieve this?

This is a pretty simple classification problem, but I could not find any previous work on this by searching on google, kaggle, and StackOverflow. Please share your valuable comments, suggestions, or references on this topic.

```
Example:

We got a ton of earnings reports last week (concrete)
Life is full of learnings (abstract)
We had a terrific quarter, and our earnings per share were over 7 percent (concrete)
We strive to achieve results, and that is our goal, our motto (abstract)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an advanced approach for solving classification problems with literally No training data which is called [`Zero-Shot Learning`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-shot_learning). Huggingface made it available and easy to use, But overall accuracy may be lesser compared to a full-featured supervised classifier with tons of examples. A simple implementation of it would look like this:

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification")
txt = [
      'We got a ton of earnings reports last week',
      'Life is full of learnings',
      'We had a terrific quarter, and our earnings per share were over 7 percent',
      'We strive to achieve results, and that is our goal, our motto'
]
candidate_labels = ["abstract", "concrete"]
res = classifier(txt, candidate_labels)
for item in res:
  print('>>> ', item['sequence'], f'The label was {item["labels"][0]} with {round(item["scores"][0], 2)} percent confidence\n\n')
```

output:

```
>>>  We got a ton of earnings reports last week The label was concrete with 0.6 percent confidence


>>>  Life is full of learnings The label was abstract with 0.52 percent confidence


>>>  We had a terrific quarter, and our earnings per share were over 7 percent The label was concrete with 0.73 percent confidence


>>>  We strive to achieve results, and that is our goal, our motto The label was concrete with 0.92 percent confidence
```

Comment: That is fantastic. Thanks. I was wondering if there was a simpler way of achieving this. I tested pos tags with spacy but I did not find any distinction b/w concrete and abstract nouns.

Comment: I will test this approach for sure and consider it! Thanks!